# E/AndroidRuntime(1549): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo:

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

Here is my modified code: 
But, I am still getting same error.
Please help, where I am doing wrong.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

int counter;
Button addOne;
Button subOne;
TextView display;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addOne=(Button) findViewById(R.id.badd);
    subOne= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bsub);
    display =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    counter=0;

     addOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        counter++;
        display.setText("Counter is"+ counter);
        }
    });


     subOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter--;
            display.setText("counter is "+ counter);
            //display.setText("counter is"+ counter);
        }
    });




}
```

My XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bat"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.iitb.practice.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/total"
    android:textSize="35sp" >

</TextView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bsub"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:text="@string/sub" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/badd"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="45dp"
     android:text="@string/add" />
```

I am getting following error:
Logcat:

```
05-19 03:42:58.520: D/AndroidRuntime(1281): Shutting down VM
```

05-19 03:42:58.520: W/dalvikvm(1281): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a96ba8)
05-19 03:42:58.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1281): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-19 03:42:58.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1281): Process: com.iitb.practice, PID: 1281
05-19 03:42:58.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1281): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.iitb.practice/com.iitb.practice.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 03:42:58.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-19 03:42:58.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-19 03:42:58.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-19 03:42:58.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-19 03:42:58.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-19 03:42:58.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-19 03:42:58.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-19 03:42:58.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 03:42:58.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-19 03:42:58.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-19 03:42:58.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-19 03:42:58.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-19 03:42:58.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1281): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 03:42:58.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at com.iitb.practice.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
05-19 03:42:58.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-19 03:42:58.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-19 03:42:58.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-19 03:42:58.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     ... 11 more
05-19 03:47:59.190: I/Process(1281): Sending signal. PID: 1281 SIG: 9

Answer (score 1):

You need first call "setContentView()" inside onCreate() before to initialize variables.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addOne=(Button)findViewById(R.id.badd);
    subOne= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bsub);
    display =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
```

Comment: Are you using a Fragment or only the activity?

Comment: thanks lot dude, I got my mistake. My button,textview code was in fragment_main.xml instead of activity_main.xml...:P

Answer (score 0):

change your oncreate start code with this

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 addOne=(Button)findViewById(R.id.badd);
    subOne= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bsub);
    display =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);            
    ......
 }
```

The problem with your code is , you are finding view before you inflate the layout that contains the view. therefore you need to first inflate layout then find the view such as button

Comment: hey..@Waqar Ahmed. I changed. But, still not working

Answer (score 0):

findViewById is being called before setContentView which inflates the layout. those views won't exist until after that call since it creates them. also as a general rule want to call super.onCreate before anything.

try moving those two lines to the top as below.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addOne=(Button)findViewById(R.id.badd);
    subOne= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bsub);
    display =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);

    ...
}
```

Comment: which line is the null pointer exception happening on. one or more of the id's you're finding probably doesn't exist in your layout.